# PIL not rendering fonts uniformly across machines

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I wrote some code that spits out an image. The code ran on my local machine yields this image:

[local http://img32.yfrog.com/img32/9476/local.png](http://img32.yfrog.com/img32/9476/local.png)

and on my webhost, it looks like this:

[host http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/858/hoste.png](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/858/hoste.png)

As you can see they are different. The top is much nicer. Both are using the same code, and the same font file (VeraMoBd.ttf), the same version of PIL (1.1.6), and the same Python version (2.6).

I googled around and there doesn't seem to be any kind of global settings relating to how PIL renders fonts... What could be causing different results?

Comment: Probably FreeType compiled with different features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would *guess* that the top image was rendered with the TrueType hinting bytecode VM enabled, where the bottom was using only FreeType's auto-hinting. (Personally I prefer the bottom!)

There are, unfortunately, [software patent](http://freetype.org/patents.html) issues which mean the hinting bytecode feature is not available on all binary builds. This is why it's not a simple run-time feature you can enable and disable, but something that is decided at compile-time. If you compile your own copy of FreeType you can enable the feature by `#define`-ing the flag TT_CONFIG_OPTION_BYTECODE_INTERPRETER in `config/ftoption.h` — if your lawyer reckons it's a good idea.